# Websocket : Starscream "masked and rsv data is not currently supported"

Tags: ios, websocket

I am developing an iOS app which required to connect with web socket server.

I can successfully connect to server but when I send request on it, it drop off the connection.

I am using [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) library for web socket.

As per server support team:
***it does not support protocol compression, but in the headers below they're requesting "permessage-deflate" from us. We'll accept uncompressed messages just fine (it's just a flag on the packet) but due to the extension they asked for, messages we send out will be compressed with that flag set.***

I send request as following using Swift

```
let dict = ["Parameter1":"value1","Parameter2":"value2"]
    
do {

                let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                var jsonString: String = String(data: data, encoding: UInt())!
                self.socket.writeString(jsonString);
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

It disconnect with server and print following message.

*"websocket is disconnected: Optional("masked and rsv data is not currently supported")"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the server support team meant is that the request from your WebSocket client application contained an HTTP header like below.

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
```

So, if your application has a line like below, remove it.

```swift
socket.headers["Sec-WebSocket-Extensions"] = "permessage-deflate"
```

Answer (score 1):

This error might also be thrown if the server doesn't accept the incoming connection (regardless of the reasons), or if the server crashed.
Basically, when this message shows up, the best action would be to check what is going on the server as you might be wasting time trying improve client code (it happened to me :)

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this issue when trying to connect to the backend WebSocket, make sure the front end and the backend version of the socket.io are compatible. Running the following command fixed the issue for me.

```
pod update
```

Updated the both to the latest and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this will fix your issue I believe. just add "wamp" in the header like this.

*

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URL)!)
 request.setValue(["wamp"].joined(separator: ","), forHTTPHeaderField: "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol")
       socket = WebSocket(request: request)
     
       socket.delegate = self
       socket.connect()
```

- 

Comment: masked and rsv data is not currently supported: issue will work after this header